# How can I add to this code so it prints "b" without removing anything?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code written in c++11 :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
    void print() const { cout << "a" << endl; }
};

void f(const A& a){
    a.print();
}
```

and I want to edit this code by adding to it but not removing anything, so it would print the letter `"b"` instead of `"a"` no matter the input.
How is that possible? I haven't found an answer on the internet?

Comment: Can you explain why you cant "remove anything"? If its a puzzle it should be on CodeGolf, not Stackoverflow.

Comment: Nope it's not a puzzle , its just what's required from me, I cant touch the given code but I can add to it

Comment: Yes, it's a puzzle. This is not an actual problem that someone would face in the real world.

Comment: This smacks of a question designed to test you about polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Use a backspace:

```
cout << "a\bb";
```

The backspace character (`\b`) takes the cursor back, then the `b` overwrites the `a`.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, it printed a (some altcode) b

Comment: Id depends on display environment. In reality writes 3 characters

Answer (score 1):

This adds to your code; doesn't remove anything and prints 'b' :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class A{
public:
void print() const {cout << "b" << endl; 
    return; 
    cout << "a" << endl ;}
};

void f(const A& a){
a.print();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap class in a namespace. Then write your own. The namespace is new. So is your new class A.

```
namespace unused {
  class A{
    public:
    void print() const { cout << "a" << endl; }
  };
}

  class A{
    public:
    void print() const { cout << "b" << endl; }
  };

void f(const A& a){
    a.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the discard property of comma

```
void print() const {cout << ("a", "b") << endl ;}
```

**--- EDIT ---**

To avoid the warning "left operand of comma operator has no effect" you can, by example, cast `"a"` to `(void)`

```
void print() const {cout << ((void)"a", "b") << endl ;}
```

Comment: its showing me the compilation error ;
left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]

Comment: @Basilm - should be a warning, not an error; and, yes, the solution is based on a left operand that has no effect.

Comment: @Basilm - added example to avoid the warning

Answer (score 0):

@zmbq gave a nice solution. Here is my take.

```
class A{ // could make this class abstract
public:
  virtual void print() const { cout << "a" << endl; }
};

class B: public A {
  void print() const { cout << "b" << endl; }
};

void f(const A& a) {
  a.print();
}

B b;
f(b); // it should print 'b'
```

This way inside function `f` the derived class's implementation will be called if the passed instance is of type `B`.

Comment: OP said "no matter the input"

Comment: but this code only works if a parameter of type B was sent to f, the thing must work for f(A& a)

Comment: That's correct - it only handles objects in type `B`.